# OneToMany With Property Tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I have two models, Task and Action. Action has a ToOneField to Task called task which works as expected. Task has a property called actions which returns an ordered list of actions which works fine, except now I want to expose it to the API with Tastypie as a ToManyField. Here is my current attempt:

```
class TaskResource(ModelResource):
    actions = fields.ToManyField('ActionResource', 'actions')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Task.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'task'

class ActionResource(ModelResource):
    task = fields.ToOneField(TaskResource, 'task')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Action.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'action'
```

This outputs:

```
"error_message": "'list' object has no attribute 'all'"
```

Does anyone have any ideas that don't involve a major redesign?

Comment: How exactly does your model look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to return the property you have to define a field in your Task resource for example like that:

```
actions = CharField('actions', readonly=True)
```

The above code will access the propert in your Task model. You can define a `dehydrate_actions` method if you want to process the returned value in a different manner than tastypie will do by default.

But if you want to do it the way you defined your resources you don't actually want to access the property in the Task model, you want to access the manager of your reverse relationship to actions and in django be default you would access it by calling action_set.
So in your Task resource:

```
actions = fields.ToManyField('ActionResource', 'action_set')
```

[More about this in the docs.](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#tastypie.fields.RelatedField.related_name)

What you have actually done in your code was trying to access a reverse relationship but accessing a property instead that isn't understood by tastypie.